# ggplot does not distinguish between variable names of class character

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am new on stackoverflow and am trying to get a boxplot going with ggplot2. I have already browsed the board extenssively, but can't find a discussion dealing with a problem similar to mine:

I got a dataframe `expression`, from which I want to create a simple boxplot.

```
> head(expression)
  Sample type FUBP1 expression
1       Tumor            60.64
2       Tumor            62.00
3       Tumor            68.78
4       Tumor            74.15
5       Tumor            59.32
6       Tumor            70.86
```

There is another sample type, called "Neighboring tissue". When I do the following command,

```
ggplot(p.p.n, aes("Sample type", "FUBP1 expression")) + geom_boxplot()
```

I get this plot:

[Boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDFeH.jpg)

It seems like R does not recognize the variables. Class of sample type is character, class of FUBP1 expression is numeric. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ggplot(p.p.n, aes_string("Sample type", "FUBP1 expression")) + geom_boxplot()`. It's easier to not use spaces in your variable names.

Comment: Convert your character type "Sample type" to factors: `as.factor()`

Comment: Already tried that @Marc P, and it does not change a thing.

Comment: Could you show me the code on how you do it?

Comment: ggplot will be expecting bare column names that appear in your data frame, so if you use strings, they are recognized as simply strings & not column names. Sometimes this is beneficial, like for setting dummy variables. Try using back ticks instead of quotation marks, as these don't conflict with interpretation as bare column names

Comment: You were both right, actually I had to convert "Sample Type" to factor and then remove quotation marks within the aes Argument. Thanks a lot Marc and Camille!